# Creating datetime data on hour frequency by using date and hour column in integer type in Hive

Tags: datetime, hive, timestamp, time-series, hiveql

I have a table including date column and hour column which is an integer type column varying from 0 to 24. I need to combine these two fields and create an hourly composite datetime field.

However, I was able to create that kind of variable by using || and cast. But I am unable to transform this code to Hive editor syntax. Can you help me with this problem

SQL Code:

```
CAST(CAST(CAST(DATE_OF_TRANSACTION AS FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS VARCHAR(11))||' '||CAST(CAST( BasketHour AS FORMAT '99:') AS VARCHAR(10))||'00:00' AS TIMESTAMP(0)) Date_Time
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example like this:

```
cast(concat(DATE_OF_TRANSACTION, ' ', lpad(BasketHour ,2,0),':00:00.0' ) as timestamp)
```